# how to make input null after submiting?

Tags: javascript, html

hello I made a to do list app and I want to clear input after submit  here is my code but it doesn't work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmT1c.png)

I expect input section to be null after I submit but every time I have to use backspace then write a new task

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [**not** a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: You should provide code in order to debug

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). See [If a variable is defined in terms of another, can it reflect changes in the binding of the other?](/q/42637782/4642212); reassigning a variable will never cause anything to mutate, including the DOM. That’s not how JavaScript works. Duplicate of [Setting innerHTML: Why won't it update the DOM?](/q/8196240/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change class="myinput" to id="myinput".

You are assigning user_input to the value of the input at that moment.

Replace your code line to get value by id:

let user_input=document.getElementById("myinput");

let user_input_value=user_input.value;

compare: if(user_input_value!='')

clear with: user_input.value='';

Answer (score 0):

### Hi

You just need to save the input element in a variable and set the value property to empty string rather than directly setting `user_input = ''`.
Also, unless there many inputs you need to loop through, it's better to use id and `document.getElementById` to identify the input you want rather than `document.querySelectorAll`

1. Save the input element as `const`

```
const user_input = document.getElementById('myInputId');
// get the value and use as needed
let user_input_value = user_input.value;
```

2. After, when you need to reset, set the input elements value to `''`

```
user_input.value = '';
```